# Does this xpath look correct?

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

```
page.getByXPath("//*[@href='http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_*'");
```

Do I need to escape any characters?

I am trying to get all ahref links on the page that have the pattern of:

```
http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_
```

so these should all be retrieved:

```
http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_asdf-asdfasdf
http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_223
http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_as.php
http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_2222233
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no wildcards in XPath. You want something like this instead:

```
page.getByXPath("//*[contains(@href,'http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_')]");
```

This relies on [the `contains` function](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_functions.asp#string). You can also use the `starts-with` function:

```
//*[starts-with(@href,'http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_')]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why it's in my answer alongside `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XPath 1.0, you cannot do wildcard (or regular expression) matches in that way. (Upgrading to 2.0 may allow that)

For this case, I'd suggest doing a 'contains' test for the prefix

//a[contains(@href, 'http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_')]

(Note, I limited the select to just a tags)

Answer (score 0):

See if your XPath library supports [`starts-with(string1,string2)`](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) and use:

```
page.getByXPath("//*[starts-with(@href, 'http://www.example.com/index.do/abc/1_')");
```

Also, can't you replace `*` by `a` ?